# Perform action when external lcd is attached or removed from Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, events, external-display

My netbook running Windows 7 Starter seems to know when I attach or remove my external monitor. But I'm wondering if there is some way to attach a script or action when these events are detected by the OS.

I'd like to try to automate a few settings changes when switching between the 10.1" screen and the 22" screen, for instance making the task bar autohide on the small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably cook something up with Autohotkey. For example, [this thread](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=23470.0) seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Craig. While AutoHotKey doesn't have an event I can hook it does have the `SetTimer` command which lets me do polling and it has the `SysGet` command which retrieves multi-monitor info. I'll definitely be experimenting with this.